# MDX Running Totals with parameters

Tags: mdx

I am trying to calculate running totals for a date range which is passed through parameters in SSRS. I know i need to use lag function, but i am not able to get it right. I tried using the following

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Rolling12Months] AS 
   SUM( 
     [Reporting Period].[Fiscal].[Fiscal Month Name].&[1]&[2013] : [Reporting Period].[Fiscal].CURRENTMEMBER,
     [Measures].[Amount]
   )
```

Comment: what does the resulting table look like - context is important in `mdx` so we need to see what what columns you have in the resulting table

Answer (score 1):

Below script will do what @whytheq's script does, only **dynamically**. It figures out the last 12 months based on the current member, which you can pass on as a slicer, or when you are in a set context, you might not need the slicer axis. I am assuming that's why you thought you needed the `LAG` function.

```
WITH SET Last12Months AS
{[Reporting Period].[Fiscal].CURRENTMEMBER.LAG(12) : [Reporting Period].[Fiscal].CURRENTMEMBER}

MEMBER [Measures].[Rolling12Months] AS 
SUM( 
    Last12Months,
    [Measures].[Amount]
   )


SELECT
     [Measures].[Rolling12Months]  ON 0
    , [Reporting Period].[Fiscal].[Fiscal Month Name].Members ON 1
FROM [YourCubeName]
WHERE [Reporting Period].[Fiscal].[Fiscal Month Name].&[1]&[2014] 
//`WHERE` clause can be left out if context is already set.
```

Comment: (upped) agree with your interpretation of the OP - I found the question a little vague.

Answer (score 0):

Your script looks ok - maybe just change to `Aggregate`:

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Rolling12Months] AS 
   Aggregate(
      [Reporting Period].[Fiscal].[Fiscal Month Name].&[1]&[2013]:[Reporting Period].[Fiscal].CurrentMember,
      [Measures].[Amount]
    )
```

So a complete script would be something like

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Rolling12Months] AS 
   Aggregate(
      [Reporting Period].[Fiscal].[Fiscal Month Name].&[1]&[2013]:[Reporting Period].[Fiscal].CurrentMember,
      [Measures].[Amount]
   )
SELECT
    {[Measures].[Amount]
    , [Measures].[Rolling12Months] } ON 0
    , [Reporting Period].[Fiscal].[Fiscal Month Name].Members ON 1
FROM [YourCubeName]
```

Comment: I think(may be wrong), he is trying to dynamically obtain the last 12 months.

Comment: Also in my opinion, the only real difference between `AGGREGATE` and `SUM` is that the former works only with additive measure while the latter works well with any kind of measure. `Measures.Amount` looks like it could be an additive measure.

Comment: @Sourav_Agasti I agree with both your comments.